# How to access resource file after building a python package on linux system

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have successfully built a python package but have run into a problem with determining files paths. My python script looks for a folder called Resources that contains some images. How can I know the path to those images if the python script can be launched from any directory because it is pip installed.

Directory tree:

```
package   
|________
         package
         |________
         |        __init__.py
         |        main.py
         |        Resources
         |        |_________
         |                   file.png
         |                   file.png
         |
         setup.py
         install.sh
```

setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name = 'package',
    version = '2.0',
    packages = ['package'],
    install_requires=[
        'pillow',
    ],
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'name = package.main:main'
        ]
    })
```

Installed with:

```
pip3 install -e
```

**Before I built the package I accessed the files like this**

```
from PIL import Image

Image.open('Resources/Icons/file.png')
```

This was not a problem when executing script from the directory with 'python main.py'

**But now that its a package and installed the file can be launched from any directory**
**In this case how to I keep track of where the Resource folder is ?**

Comment: First, you don't have Resources in your package: you've forgotten to add them in `setup.py`. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+add+package+data

Comment: Thank you i was able to get with pkg_resources, I was using a hack way with __file__ but pkg_resources is what i was looking for. That along with adding package_dir and package_data to setup.py